# How to fetch N most recent entries from DynamoDB using Lambda Function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have items in a DDB table with a field labeled Timestamp that has date/time string values such as these: `2023-11-14T01:22:53.945Z`

All I want to do is query my database to return N entries sorted from most recent based on this timestamp value. I'm reading a bunch of posts talking about GSI ... ranges ... sort keys. A little overwhelming and not sure how to approach.

I don't really have a code example, just tried a few things from ChatGPT and other SO posts, but some of them involve having the Timestamp as secondary keys, some as GSI's, not sure what the proper approach is. (using JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a common use case you will need a GSI. Ordering in DynamoDB is only maintained by the sort key, for that reason you'll need your timestamp to be the sort key. Now, what should be the partition key?

If your overall table throughput doesn't surpass 1000 WCU then you can simply use a static value for the partition key of your GSI:

| GSIPK | Timestamp | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-11-20T20:00:000Z | some data |
| 1 | 2023-11-20T21:00:000Z | some data |
| 1 | 2023-11-20T22:00:000Z | some data |
| .. | .. | .. |
| 1 | 2023-11-29T16:00:000Z | some data |

With this data model you can get the latest N records, or the oldest N records using the `Query` command. In SQL it would look like the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my-table.my-index 
WHERE GSIPK = 1 
LIMIT 10
```

If your table needs more than 1000 WCU then you could cause a hot partition on your index by using a static key. You'd have to write shard your GSI meaning you have to use a random (known) character as the GSIpk and that would also cause you to make N requests.

Comment: The table will have require few WCU. To give some more context, this table stores weather info on cities. I currently have the city/country name together as the partition key (location) and no sort key. I have queries where I search by the specific location, and I am currently working on a query that returns the most recent N entries based on timestamp field as mentioned. One question, why do I need both a sort key and a GSI, as well a dummy static field in each row? Really seems like overkill for such a simple operation. (New to NoSQL/DDB, this is all foreign to me).

Comment: Curious to why you decided to go with NoSQL? DynamoDB is a key value store, but with additional features. Your use case is not key-value, as you're looking for global sort order across all items. For that reason you need to use a static value and a global secondary index to provide you an alternative view.